# Encoding new data in the same format that encoded data used for training RF model

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataset with numerical and categorical data.  I have scaled and encoded respectively the columns Using one-hot-encoding.  I trained a Random Forest model with the data.  After acheiving good results with my test data I wnat to use the model to predict results with new data.  The problem is I don't know how can I efficiently transform my categorical data the same encoding used on training and testing data.  I used the same encoder but instead of having and array of 9 columns I only get 3 columns for one new data point.

I tried already using the same encoder but I do not get the same number of columns.

```py
categorical_columns=[['Product1','Segment1','Yes'],['Product1','Segment1','No'],
                    ['Product3','Segment2','No'],['Product2','Segment1','Yes'],
                    ['Product5','Segment2','No'],['Product4','Segment1','No'],
                    ['Product4','Segment1','Yes'],['Product1','Segment2','Yes']]
df=pd.DataFrame(categorical_columns,columns=['Product_Type','Segment','Special_Feature'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder=OneHotEncoder(categories = "auto", handle_unknown = "ignore",sparse=False)
ohe=encoder.fit_transform(df)

new_categorical_data=np.array([['Product3','Segment1','Yes']])
ohe_new=encoder.fit_transform(new_categorical_data)
```

I expect an array like:[[0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,]] and I get an array like
[[1,1,1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. Simply exchange the last line to:

```
ohe_new = encoder.transform(new_categorical_data)  # not fit_transform
```

Otherwise `encoder` forgets what it has previously seen during the first `fit_transform`.